# Computing the Fourier Series of a sound recording

Tags: theory

More specifically, my question is:

"Can computers find the Fourier Series for any recording of a single note on a musical instrument or do FS only exist for the basic wave forms, i.e. triangle, square and sawtooth?"

I am asking myself this question since I found the FS coefficients of these basic wave forms by hand for a school project, but also wanted to model recordings of single notes on a piano. However, I have realized that the amplitude time graphs of my recordings look only vaguely like these wave forms, but rather like finite sums of sine or cosine waves.

Hence, I was considering using some program to find the coefficients instead - provided this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically, a Fourier *series* can only represent a *periodic* wave form, i.e. one which repeats exactly, and theoretically continues for ever with no beginning and no end. To find the Fourier coefficients, you only need one cycle of the waveform. I would guess that is what you did in your school project.

In practice, you can take a finite-length chunk of "real" audio (like a single piano note) and calculate its Fourier series, but unless the start and end of the sample "match up," the result may be fairly meaningless unless you take some precautions.

Without going into the math, if you play back your sample of audio in a loop and there is a "click" or "thump" every time it cycles from the end to the start, the Fourier series you calculate will be for the sound you want, *plus that unwanted click*, and the unwanted part may swamp the "interesting" data.

There are ways to get round this by smoothing the data so the start and end *do* match up neatly, but the smoothing process also affects the Fourier series you calculate.

If you want to experiment with real recorded sound, I suggest getting some free audio-editing software, for example Audacity (http://www.audacityteam.org/). Those programs usually have an option to calculate Fourier series in a useful way, and display the results graphically.

Fourier series are important theoretically in mathematics, but in practice there are better ways to identify the frequency components of time-varying signals. For example, after the first few milliseconds while the hammer is hitting the strings, a piano note actually consists of a set of *decaying* oscillations. The various frequencies are not *exactly* at integer multiples of the fundamental frequency, and the rate of decay is different for each one. A straightforward "Fourier series" calculation can't give you those details, but there are other numerical methods which can - though this is a fairly specialised topic which isn't covered at all in most bachelor-level university degrees in math, physics, or engineering.

Actually, you can *see* that the frequencies are not exact multiples without doing any math, if you record a low note on the piano until the sound has completely died away and plot the wave form near the end of the recording. The sound will then be mostly two components (an octave apart) with the frequency ratio very slightly *bigger* than 2:1. You should be able to see the relative phase of the two components changing, as you scroll along the graph of the wave form.

Comment: But a periodic waveform could easily be a combination of frequencies such as produced with one instrument which puts out sawtooth (violin) and another which puts out square (trumpet), so long as the summed waveform is periodic.

Answer (score 1):

Fourier series (and as a special case, DFT and its more special computing variant FFT) make *interpretable* sense only for periodic signals.  FFT is useful as a building block for various frequency analysis tools, and it is useful as a building block for digital filtering (since it can be used for fast convolution).  Employing an FFT as the workhorse inside of analytic tools as well as in adaptive filtering (where the filter is non-constant) is sort of an art form.  One frequently used tool is "short-time FFT" where overlapping transforms on "windowed" data are performed and displayed time-averaged.  The important thing is that the window length should not really exceed the rate with which the frequency content changes (so it should be shorter than "note length") but it also needs to be long enough to actual recognize frequencies.  There are actually techniques which have finer time resolution for higher frequencies.

Audio compression programs tend to try making use of sound frequencies and relations by rather tracking LPCs (linear prediction coefficients) and then using delta compression on the remaining residue signal.  These techniques are comparatively robust against coarse quantisation of the residue signal: the well-identifiable frequency components tend to get represented reasonably well using the LPCs, and noisier signals (which are mostly left in the residue signal) are comparatively hard to distinguish in detail anyway.

So in short: this is a really wide field of techniques and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: for all practical purposes, you always only need a finite number of coefficients, because ultrasonic frequencies aren't relevant. I.e., your *L*₂(ℝ) ­­↔ *L*₂(ℂ) continuous Fourier transform boils down to a ℝ²ⁿ ↔ ℂⁿ [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), and that can be calculated efficiently with [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithms.

However, the Fourier transform alone isn't actually that useful to model many instrument sounds – it can basically just describe very short time snippets. While you can in principle also calculate the FT of an entire symphony, most of the actual musical information will then be encoded in very delicate phase relations within narrow frequency bands.

To effectively describe instrument sounds you thus also need to retain some time-domain information: how the FT changes *throughout the note duration*. This is accomplished by [short-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).